# Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is a differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$ and $f$ and $f'$ both
have finite limits at infinity, then lim as $x$ goes to infinity of $f'(x) = 0$. Hint: apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ for large values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)$, there exists $N$ such that $x>N$ implies that $\mid f(x)-L\mid <1$,  for every integer $n>N$, $f(n+n)-f(n)=f'(c_n)n$, $c_n\in [2n,n]$.

This implies that $\mid f(n+n)-f(n)\mid =n\mid f'(c_n)\mid <1$ this implies that $\mid f'(c_n)\mid< 1/n$, since $\lim_nc_n=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)$ exists, you deduce that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Your formulas will look better if you use "|" instead of "\mid."

Comment: @BarryCipra I've always found it hit and miss with | or \mid. Sometimes with | it ends up to close to some symbols

Comment: (+1) One more thing. This maybe off topic but how do you think and imagine what epsilon will work(like in this question you took 1). When you saw this question, what thought process went into your mind. I always feel like I am stuck at coming up with such proofs. I am currently solving as many problems as I can so as to develop some maturity in real analysis. Will it help? I would be thankful  to you if you can comment something on  this. Cheers.