# Applying mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

My question is about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845995/mean-value-theorem). We know that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and  $f(x)$ has a finite limit (let's say $L$) as $x\to\infty.$   My exact question is if we really need the assumption that $f'(x)$ has a finite limit as $x\to\infty.$

We can apply the mean value theorem to $f$ on the interval of the form $[n,n+1].$ Then, we have that there is a $x_n \in (n,n+1)$, such that:
$$f'(x_n) = \frac{f(n+1) - f(n)}{(n+1) - n}= f(n+1) - f(n).$$ Now let $n\to \infty$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n+1) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n) = L$, thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f'(x_n) = 0,$ with $x_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty.$

There is always the case I might miss something.

Comment: it could be that $f'(x_n)$ does not exist

Comment: @gt6989b I edited a liitle bit my question. The function is differentiable on $(0,\infty).$

Comment: indeed, but that does not guarantee differentiability *at* $\infty$

Comment: You have shown that there exists a number $n<x_n<n+1$ such that $f'(x_n)$ is arbitrarily small.  But that does not imply that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV So, actually I have shown there is at least one sequence $f'(x_n)$ that converges to zero, right? But since (in the original problem) $f'(x)$ has a finite limit as $x\to \infty$ , every convergent sequence $f'(a_n)$ will converge to the same limit, thus it is sufficient to find the limit of just one convergent sequence. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if the limit of $f'$ exists, then your method is valid.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin\left(x^2\right)}{x}
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0
$$
yet
$$
f'(x)=2\cos\left(x^2\right)-\frac{\sin\left(x^2\right)}{x^2}
$$
which has no limit.

Comment: Thank you for the example!